# Oracle - group by in having clause

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, having-clause

My query looks like this

```
select f.entity, MAX(to_char(f.whencreated, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) from fan f
group by f.entity
having MAX((f.whencreated)) >
(select MAX((b.endtime)) from brun b
where b.cny# = f.cny#
and b.entity = f.entity
group by b.entity, f.entity);
```

I get error

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

In this query, I want to select f.entity if the Max(whencreated) of that entity in table f is more than the MAX((b.endtime)) of the same entity in table brun.

the tables look like as follows:

Table fan:

```
ENTITY      WHENCREATED

A           09/01/2020 12:34:00

A           10/01/2020 12:12:12

B           08/01/2020 12:34:00

B           10/01/2020 12:12:12
```

Table burn:

```
ENTITY      ENDTIME

A           09/02/2020 12:34:00

A           09/04/2020 12:12:12

B           08/01/2020 12:34:00

B           11/01/2020 12:12:12
```

The query should return

```
A           10/01/2020 12:12:12
```

because the max(brun.endtime) for the Entity A is 09/04/2020 12:12:12, which is less than the max(fan.whencreated) for the Entity A, which is 10/01/2020 12:12:12.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic.

Comment: Your inner query is having a group on entities whereas they were not selected. May be due to that?

Comment: I added sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try with a different approach:

```
with temp as
  (select 
     f.entity,
     max(f.whencreated) max_fwhen,
     max(b.endtime) max_bend
   from fan f join brun b on b.dny# = f.cny#
                         and b.entity = f.entity
   group by f.entity
  )
select entity
from temp
where max_fwhen > max_bend;
```

By the way, don't MAX a string; I believe you want to work with dates, not strings. You'll get unexpected results as e.g. 08/25/1920 is "larger" than 02/12/2021.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the reason for the error is that your subquery in the `HAVING` clause references `f.cny#`.  Since that column is not in the `GROUP BY` clause of the main query, it can't be referenced at this point.

I think you need to clarify what it is you are trying to achieve.  "The same entity" implies that same value for the `entity` columns, and nothing else.

Comment: I added the data and the expected result.

Comment: @Jean OK - your sample data doesn't include the `cny#` column at all.  Why are you using it in your query?

Answer (score 0):

> select f.entity if the Max(whencreated) of that entity in table f is more than the MAX((b.endtime))

Well, how about aggregating before joining:

```
select f.entity
from (select f.entity, max(whencreated)as maxwc
      from fan f
      group by f.entity
     ) f join
     (select b.entity, max(b.endtime) as maxet
      from brun b
      group by b.entity
     ) b
     on f.entity = b.entity and f.maxwc > b.maxet
```